# JavaEE : Nullpointer while trying to expose my Rest Web Service

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-ws

Hello i'm Trying to expose my Rest web Service but i keep getting Null pointer exception . i don't understand my fault because i got the code from another project and it works perfectly but inn my project i got the error please if you can identify the error help me.

i initialized my Service in Employee Bean this way :

EmployeServiceASP employeServiceASP= new EmployeServiceASP();

EmployeeBean:

```
@GET
@Path("/all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response getserviceHello() {
    return `Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(employeServiceASP.getAll()).build();`
}
```

EmployeBeanImport:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import tn.esprit.PiDev.persistence.Employe;
import tn.esprit.PiDev.services.EmployeServiceASP;
```

Employee Service:

```
    @Override
public List<Employe> getAll() {
      Query q=em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employe e");
        return q.getResultList();
}
```

RestActivator:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestActivator extends Application {

}
```

HEre's the error :

> 00:05:23,165 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-39) UT005023:
>   Exception handling request to /PiDev-web/rest/employe/all:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   tn.esprit.PiDev.presentation.mbeans.EmployeBeanASP.getserviceHello(EmployeBeanASP.java:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
>     ... 32 more

PostMan Result: 
[image]

Comment: Please post where you have declared and initialized `employeServiceASP`. I suspect it has not been initialized.

Comment: @Kartik i declareded as  EmployeServiceASP employeServiceASP;

Comment: ok, but did you initialize it? like `employeServiceASP = new EmployeServiceASP()` or using `@Autowired`?

Comment: @Kartik i intialiwed it this way : EmployeServiceASP employeServiceASP= new EmployeServiceASP(); but it's the same

Comment: where have you written this statement? can you please update the question with this piece of code?

Comment: @Kartik in EmployeBean

Comment: @Kartik   import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import tn.esprit.PiDev.persistence.Employe;
import tn.esprit.PiDev.services.EmployeServiceASP;

Comment: thanks you i will try to use dependencies injection

Comment: you should debug to see exactly what is `null` in this line `return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(employeServiceASP.getAll()).build();` and go from there